# Arrange <p> elements in date order using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime

Hi Guys I have a list with data-date containing the date of order it needs to appear in.

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<p data-date="Fri, 26 Aug 2011 20:58:39 GMT">item 1</p>
<p data-date="Fri, 24 Aug 2011 20:58:39 GMT">item 2</p>
<p data-date="Fri, 25 Aug 2011 20:58:39 GMT">item 3</p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("p").sort(function(a,b){
    return new Date($(a).attr("data-date")) > new Date($(b).attr("data-date"));
}).each(function(){
    $("body").prepend(this);
})
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ3gg/2/)

it seems to work 50%

Comment: Your demo seems to work? Can you provide examples of when it doesn't?

Comment: Sorry i just update jsfiddle here is my code - http://jsfiddle.net/CQ3gg/302/

Comment: You're still sorting `p` elements in your jQuery selector...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the `dd/mm/yyyy` format dates manually. Also, the `sort` function expects you to return a number greater tham less than or equal to zero; not `true` or `false`. Revised function:

```
$("#posts li").sort(function (a, b) {
    var aComp = $(a).attr("data-date").split("/");
    var aDate = new Date(+aComp[2], +aComp[1] - 1, +aComp[0]);
    var bComp = $(b).attr("data-date").split("/");
    var bDate = new Date(+bComp[2], +bComp[1] - 1, +bComp[0]);
    return aDate - bDate;
}).prependTo("#posts");
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/CQ3gg/304/)

Comment: just one question, how can I toggle between ascending and descending

Comment: Change `a - b` to `b - a` in the sort function.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer is a bit longer but it is the most perfect one that I have tested